# I have been serially downvoted and upvoted posts are being deleted

Tags: support, downvotes, serial-voting

Starting yesterday, my old upvoted posts are rapidly being downvoted and deleted on Stack Overflow, and I am losing reputation a lot. Scripts and bots aren't detecting this. You can see my reputation history. What can I do at this moment?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks like a bug to me as the Roomba is supposed to only take into account downvotes at least 2 days old. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269392/323179

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64255181/on-line-12-there-is-an-invalid-syntax-and-im-not-sure-why) was deleted by the roomba.
- The same thing happened to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64296061/i-cannot-get-the-program-to-keep-going-after-it-prints-invalid-number).
- And also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64526686/write-a-function-that-takes-in-a-list-of-distinct-numbers-and-return-the-list-wi)
- [And this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59872486/how-to-combine-two-commands-in-windows)

The following [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) rule is the relevant one in this case:

> If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...
>
> - not closed as a duplicate
> - has a score of 0 or less
> - is not locked
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - has no accepted answer
> - has no pending reopen votes
> - has not been edited in the past 9 days

Your answer had a single upvote, and a downvote then changed your answer score to 0, so the roomba then kicked in and deleted the question. If those answers were all voted on by the same person then perhaps the roomba deletion sidestepped the serial reversal process.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64423647/split-multiple-dict-into-single-dict) however was deleted because the user was deleted. Either they self deleted or a moderator deleted the user. Either way, the question went away with the user and so did your answer.

If you keep answering questions that end up closed, perhaps you should look at what's common about such questions. Closed questions that aren't edited to be on-topic are always in danger of being deleted.

Finally [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64656382/shorten-if-statement-with-multiple-lines-into-one-lines) you deleted yourself.

Comment: OK that covers the deletion and roomba concept, but what about the downvotes? Who cast them?

Comment: All votes are anonymous by design. Exceptions are close and delete votes.

Comment: @Wasif After the posts deletion, there are only 3 surviving downvoted posts, and those do not seem clustered. There seems to be very little left to reverse.

Comment: Undelete and reopen votes are also public, but they're basically the other half of the votes Luuklag mentioned

Comment: Serial voting reversals also happen on deleted posts, @WasifHasan. If you open up the answers that were downvoted to 0 and notice they now have a score of 1, *then* it was serial voting. If not, it probably wasn't.